# While working with CSV file without pandas in python , what's the internal behavior of this program below?

Tags: python, csv

**I couldn't get the logic of how 'd' in the for loop works.Can someone explain in detail?**

```
import csv
%precision 2
with open('manual_flow_input_grade_8.csv') as csvfile:
mfig =list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))

for d in mfig:
    print(d['Code'])

8.ag5.u.1
8.ag5.u.2
8.ag5.u.3

#Here's the info about csv data :  
print(mfig[0].keys())

#odict_keys(['Code', 'Tag', 's=1', 's2<0', 'M', 'Code_', 'Tag_', 's=1_', 's<0_', 'PAR', 'CHI'])
print(mfig[0].values())

#odict_values(['8.ag5.u.1', 'AG5.1', 'OK', '7.ag4.ap.1', '', 'ag5', 'ag5', 'OK', 'ag4', 'ag4', 'ag7'])
```

Comment: This code won't run, I assume the `print` following the for should be indented?

Comment: @Morgoth thanks i've edited that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the for-loop basically loops through the rows of the CSV file. In each loop iteration the variable `d` gets filled with a [dictionary object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that contains all data from a single CSV-file row (possibly the name `d` was meant to be shorthand for 'dictionary'). The keys inside `d` are column names from the CSV-file, and the paired values are row data values from the CSV-file.

The expression `d['Code']` returns the data value from dictionary `d` corresponding to the key `'Code'`. In other words: it returns the CSV-file row data value found in the `'Code'` column.